# Akka http -ERROR :Substream Source cannot be materialized more than once If Payload size increased

Tags: scala, rest, akka, akka-http

I am working with Akka Http, where I have defined a route as

```
val route = (path(HttpConstants.CreateJob) & post) {
    (entity(as[JobDetailsEntity]) & entity(as[JobEntity])) {
      (jobDetailsEntity: JobDetailsEntity, jobEntity: JobEntity) =>
        val updatedJobEntity = jobEntity.copy(runningSince = DateTime.now().getMillis)
        val updatedJobDetailsEntity = jobDetailsEntity.copy(runningSince = DateTime.now().getMillis).copy(modify_date = DateTime.now().getMillis)
        complete {
          createJobDetails(updatedJobDetailsEntity).map(_.asJson)
          createJob(updatedJobEntity).map(_.asJson)
        }
    }
```

Here I am trying to unmarshal two entites in the same POST call which works when my json Payload id small i.e few bytes then its works fine , as soon as the payload size increases i.e around 10-20 kb it throws error :

`Substream Source cannot be materialized more than once`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please see https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/745#issuecomment-271571342

In short, if you need to unmarshal your entity twice you should use the toStrict first to make sure the entire entity is buffered in memory, otherwise it will be drained by the first unmarshalling process and not available for the second.

Only accidentally it happens to work without toStrict if the entity is small enough that it fits in akka's internal buffer, then there's actually no draining involved.

Comment: How to I make an entity as in my case `toStrict`

Answer (score 0):

> Note that some directives force an implicit `toStrict` operation, such
>   as `entity(as[String])` and similar ones.

Refer to AKKA docs: [Server-Side handling of streaming HTTP Entities](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/implications-of-streaming-http-entity.html#consuming-the-http-request-entity-server-)

Comment: @Freeman feel free to refer above mention link for "How to I make an entity as in my case `toStrict` ?"