# Akka Http read entity fails with Substream Source cannot be materialized more than once

Tags: akka-stream, akka-http

When I am trying to consume the data on server into memory and later I want to create strict entity with it, but getting `Substream Source cannot be materialized more than once` error message.

As far as I know I am not consuming the data from the request more than once (from application layer not investigated akka-http library layer). Requests are successful with small chunk of data, failing with bigger (around 10 KB) chunk of data

**First try:**

```
 if (!entity.isChunked()) {
    entity.dataBytes.runFold(ByteString.empty)(_ ++ _).flatMap { encryptedBody =>
      decrypt(encryptedBody).map { decrypted =>
        HttpEntity(decrypted)
      }
    }
  }
```

also tried following (suggestion in [Akka http -ERROR :Substream Source cannot be materialized more than once If Payload size increased](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44950948/akka-http-error-substream-source-cannot-be-materialized-more-than-once-if-payl)) but no luck

**Second try (with strict):**

```
entity.toStrict(4.seconds).flatMap { strictEntity =>
  decrypt(strictEntity.data).map { decrypted =>
    HttpEntity(decrypted) 
  }
}
```

AkkaHttp Version: `10.0.13` ( We are in the process of migrating to latest version, we are kind of stuck with older version)
Akka Version : `2.4.20`

Any kind of help would be great.

**Stack trace is:**

```
[info] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Substream Source cannot be materialized more than once
[info]  at akka.stream.impl.fusing.SubSource$$anon$4.setCB(StreamOfStreams.scala:725)
[info]  at akka.stream.impl.fusing.SubSource$$anon$4.preStart(StreamOfStreams.scala:735)
[info]  at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.init(GraphInterpreter.scala:520)
[info]  at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.init(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:380)
[info]  at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.tryInit(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:538)
[info]  at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.preStart(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:586)
[info]  at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundPreStart(Actor.scala:510)
[info]  at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundPreStart(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:529)
[info]  at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:590)
[info]  at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1_aroundBody2(ActorCell.scala:461)
[info]  at akka.actor.ActorCell$AjcClosure3.run(ActorCell.scala:1)
[info]  at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149)
[info]  at akka.kamon.instrumentation.ActorSystemMessageInstrumentation$$anonfun$aroundSystemMessageInvoke$1.apply(ActorSystemMessageInstrumentation.scala:34)
[info]  at kamon.trace.Tracer$.withContext(TracerModule.scala:58)
[info]  at akka.kamon.instrumentation.ActorSystemMessageInstrumentation.aroundSystemMessageInvoke(ActorSystemMessageInstrumentation.scala:34)
[info]  at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:1)
[info]  at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:483)
[info]  at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:282)
[info]  at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:223)
[info]  at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
[info]  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
[info]  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
[info]  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
[info]  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Failing because the entity was read more than once.**

In the beginning, I could not figure it out because the reading was happening at the time validation, and it is deeply buried in the validations. (one of the validation depends on body content)

I tried strict entity conversion after the validations, so it did not work out.